# C# open xml unable to read string values

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core, openxml, iformfile

Hi I am using open xml to read excel in my .Net application. I have method which accepts row and columns as input parameters and returns value for that particular cell. Below is my implementation.

```
public List<ServicePortDto> GetServicePorts(IFormFile formFile, Dictionary<string, int> starRowForPorts)
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(formFile.OpenReadStream(), false))
    {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
        List<int> portRows = new();
        int counter = 0;
        IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
        foreach (var sheet in sheets)
        {
            int startRowPort = starRowForPorts.Where(x=>x.Key == sheet.Name.Value).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
            string relationshipId = sheet.Id.Value;
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
            Worksheet workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
            SheetData sheetData = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
            IEnumerable<Row> rows = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();
            rows = rows.Where(x=>x.RowIndex >= startRowPort);
            foreach (Row row in rows)
            {
                if(row.RowIndex >= startRowPort)
                {
                    string portName = GetCell(workSheet, "B", startRowPort).InnerText;

                    if (portName != null)
                    {
                        counter = counter + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return new List<ServicePortDto>();
}
```

Below is GetCell method.

```
private static Cell GetCell(Worksheet worksheet, string columnName, int rowIndex)
{
    Row row = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Elements<Row>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex);

    if (row != null)
    {
        return row.Elements<Cell>().FirstOrDefault(c => string.Compare(c.CellReference.Value, columnName + rowIndex, true) == 0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The problem is with above method is if there is any string data in cell then it reads as some integer. I am not sure why this is happening. Integer values reads properly. Only issue with String/Text fields. May I know what I am missing here? Can someone please help me with this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Instead of using the low-level Open XML SDK use a library like ExcelDataReader, EPPlus or one of the many Excel libraries in NuGet. What you try to do may only need a single line. BTW what *are* you trying to do? Reading a single cell is trivial in *all* libraries and not very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Open XML, cell values are stored as shared strings or directly as inline strings, and you need to handle them accordingly.

```
private static string GetCellValue(Cell cell, SharedStringTablePart stringTablePart)
{
    if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
    {
        if (stringTablePart != null)
        {
            SharedStringItem sharedStringItem = stringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>().ElementAt(int.Parse(cell.InnerText));
            return sharedStringItem.Text?.Text;
        }
    }
    else if (cell.CellValue != null)
    {
        return cell.CellValue.Text;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi @FortyTwo, Thanks for your answer.  If there are multiple sheets in my excel then what should i pass to above method? is it possible to pass worksheet to above method?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of the Open XML SDK use one of the high level Excel libraries in NuGet like ExcelDataReader, EPPlus, ClosedXML and many others (some of them a lot faster). The Open XML SDK is very low level, almost at the level of XML elements.

Using [EPPlus](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus) for example, all this code could be replaced with just :

```
using var fileStream=formFile.OpenReadStream();
using ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(fileStream);
ExcelWorksheet sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

var range=sheet.Cells["b:b"];
foreach(var cell in range)
{
    ...
}
```

You can use LINQ to count non-empty cells:

```
var filledCount=sheet.Cells["b:b"].Where(c=>c.Value!=null).Count();
```

[ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) creates an IDbDataReader wrapper over an Excel sheet that can be used to read data into a DataTable, sent to a database etc:

```
using var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(fileStream);
do
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (!reader.IsDbNull(1))
        {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

You can use that reader with SqlBulkCopy to import the data into SQL Server:

```
using var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);
bcp.DestinationTableName = "SomeTable"; 
...
bcp.WriteToServer(reader);
```

Comment: EPPlus requires a commercial license, while OpenXML SDK has an MIT license. Just adding this comment here, so that if one chooses this solution, one is aware of it ;).

Comment: @FortyTwo the comment is inaccurate. It's dual, not commercial. ClosedXML and ExcelDataReader are MIT.  All libraries have licenses, including Open XML SDK. . You're paying for Open XML SDK with your own (or rather the company's) lost time and revenue anyway. There are a *lot* of Excel libraries in NuGet, far smaller and faster than the Open XML SDK